# Retrieve from database then display in a drop down

Tags: php

I created a small script that allows the user to select from a drop down where there data is retrieved from the database, My problem is the information retrieve doesnt have an option for the user to select I want the dropdown to show an option to select from the drop down and display something like **You selected 1) Name and 2) Surname** I also want to retrieve two rows eg. name and surname..... How do I go about displaying?
after he/she has selected

My Code so far

```
      ////Selectiong from twoo tables
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM selections ORDER BY id ASC") or die(mysql_error());
$result = mysql_num_rows($query);

// If no results have been found or when table is empty
if ($result == 0) {

    echo 'No results have been found.';

} else {

    // Display form
    echo '<form name="form" method="post" action="test.php">';
    echo '<select name="id" id="id">';

    // Fetch results from database and list in the select box
    while ($fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

        echo '<option id="'.$fetch['name'].'">'.$fetch['surname'].'</option>';
    }

    echo '</select>';
    echo '</form>';

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 2 things. 1. Your question is not clear. Do you mind rephrasing? And 2. [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0):

you have to use client side scripting to retrieve what users choose.

You can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function(){
              $('#write_in_div').click(function(){
                 var name    = $('#names').val();
                 var surname = $('#surnames').val();
                 var email   = $('#emails').val();
                 $('#write_in_div').text("Name: "+name+" -  Surname: "+surname+" - Email: "+email);
              });
           });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php require 'content.php';?>
    </body>
</html>
```

with `content.php`:

```
<?php
    $resource_names = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT NAME FROM selections ORDER BY id ASC");
    $names = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($resource_names)){
        $names[] = $row[0]    
    } 
    $resource_surnames = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT SURNAME FROM selections ORDER BY id ASC"); 
    $surnames = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($resource_surnames)){
        $surnames[] = $row[0];
    } 
    $resource_emails   = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT EMAIL FROM selections ORDER BY id ASC");    
    $emails = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($resource_emails)){
        $emails[] = $row[0];
    }
    if(count($emails) <= 0 || count($surnames) <= 0 || count($emails) <= 0){
        echo 'No results have been found.';
    } else {

        // Display form
        echo '<form name="form" method="post" action="test.php">';

        //Names dropdown:
        echo '<select name="id" id="names">';
        foreach($names as $name) echo "<option id='$name'>$name</option>";
        echo '</select>';

        //Surnames dropdown
        echo '<select name="id" id="surnames">';
        foreach($surnames as $surname) echo "<option id='$surname'>$surname</option>";
        echo '</select>';

        //Emails dropdown
        echo '<select name="id" id="emails">';
        foreach($emails as $email) echo "<option id='$email'>$email</option>";
        echo '</select>';

        echo "<button id='write_in_div'>Click me!</button>";

        echo '</form>';

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: This does display the data but it doesnt show a user something like a button which shows what type of data he/selected but it does populate a dropp down, Can we make create an option where a user clicks something from a drop down?

Comment: sorry but i don't understand what you need.. could you explain better?

Comment: I have a table called selections with the following fiels name, surname and email I want to retrieved from that table (assuming the table has many names and surnames and emails in it) fields selected by user say for example for NAME user Selected Jack, for SURNAME White then for EMAIL (at)gmail.com That info be displayed as Jack White (at)mail.com..... but the user must get these values from 3 dropdowns

Comment: ok, if i understood, you have three select: one with names, one with surnames and one with emails. If you see edits, i create a button that on click prints what you need into a div.

Comment: Its works Now, only one thing is missing if the user has selected from the 3drop dows the Click me! button does not show him what he selected!

Comment: see edits.. i just replace the text of the button with the three dropdown selected items

Comment: Is there a way we can make a Javascript to be inside content.php so we can use one file?

Comment: Jack cn the file that Im using is content.php now how do i include this jqury script

Comment: you have to open jquery.js, copy the content and paste it inside a <script> tag, but it is not a good thing to do. If you want to use jquery in another page, it is correct to have a separated file.